# Generically typed classes in collections in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, types, collections, typing

I'm having a problem with a generic class I'm creating in Scala. I have the following class:

```
class Channel[T, U](val endPoint : EventSource[U], val filter : Occurrence[T] => Boolean,
    val map : Occurrence[T] => Occurrence[U]) {

    def send(occurrence : Occurrence[T]) {
        if (filter(occurrence)) {
            endPoint.occur(map(occurrence))
        }
    }
}
```

Here a Channel[T,U] can be seen as a way of propagating an Occurrence[T] from an EventSource[T] to an EventSource[U]. The occurrence is only sent if the filter function is true and if so the occurrence is passed to map and the result of this is sent.

This class seems to compile and function correctly. My problem is that I want to attach several Channels to an EventSource[T] instance so it can propagate Occurrences to several different EventSources of different types. My confusion is basically how to do this:

```
class EventSource[T] {
    var List[Channel[T,U]] list = ...
}
```

What is U here? T is simply referenced from the type T in the EventSource that `list` belongs to (is a member of).

Sorry if this is a vague or confusing!

EDIT: I should have noted that I also want to be able to append to this list as in:

```
list = list ++ List[Channel[T, U](new Channel[T, U](endPoint, filter, map))
```

Is the append the real problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain typing you really need to **use the wild card _ type**. This allows you to define list in such a way where you care about the U parameter of the Channel type when adding it to the list but not when sending an occurrence to all the channels in the list. The following compiles but as it stands it is rather circular. You need a sub class of channel that does something other than send it to another EventSource.

```
class Occurrence[T]
class Channel[T, U](val endPoint : EventSource[U], val filter : Occurrence[T] => Boolean,
    val map : Occurrence[T] => Occurrence[U]) {
    def send(occurrence : Occurrence[T]) {
        if (filter(occurrence))
            endPoint.occur(map(occurrence))
    }
}
class EventSource[T] {
  var list: List[Channel[T,_]]  = Nil
  def addChannel[U]( endPoint : EventSource[U], filter : Occurrence[T] => Boolean, map : Occurrence[T] => Occurrence[U]) {
    list = list ++ List[Channel[T, U]](new Channel[T, U](endPoint, filter, map))
  }
  def occur( occurrence : Occurrence[T] ) {
    list foreach { _.send( occurrence ) }
  }
}
```

Comment: "You need a sub class of channel that does something other than send it to another EventSource" - I don't understand what you mean by this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use Any:

```
class EventSource[T] {
  val list: List[Channel[T, Any]] = ...
```

EDIT: Is your code example where you use append copied? Because I noted that you're missing the types for Channel. 
Also, if you just want to add one element to your list you can use cons, which adds the new element at the beginning of your list:

```
Channel[Your, Types](your, para, meters)::list
```

If you for some reason absolutely want to add the new element to the *end* of that list, you can use `:+`.

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work with appends. I've updated the question with what I mean.

Comment: This annoyingly has the same problem as U is invariant in Channel so a
`Channel[T, U]` (where U is anything) can't be `cons`ed to a `List[T, Any]`. Thanks for the help and the quick updates?

Comment: @Oetzi, you have to type the Channel when you cons it, meaning you can't write `Channel[T, U]::list`, you have to write `Channel[Real, Type]::list`. Or did I missunderstand you? What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: error: type mismatch;
 found   : com.github.oetzi.echo.core.Channel[T,T]
 required: com.github.oetzi.echo.core.Channel[T,Any]
Note: T <: Any, but class Channel is invariant in type U.
You may wish to define U as +U instead. (SLS 4.5)
    this.edges = new Channel[T, T](newEvent, func, occ => occ) :: this.edges